# Error adding Database to TSA Cluster - db2haicu

Tags: db2, clustering

I'm testing TSA Clustering using two test servers. It's replicating our production environment.

I'm using two nodes shared disk topology.

When running db2haicu, I am getting the following error in the last step, that is, when adding the database to the cluster.

```
Adding virtual IP address 'x.x.x.x' to the domain ...

Adding virtual IP address 'x.x.x.x' to the domain was successful.

The following databases can be made highly available:

 Database: TESTDB

Do you want to make all active databases highly available? [1]

1. Yes
2. No

1

Adding database 'TESTDB' to the cluster domain ...



The db2haicu utility hangs on like this until I kill the process.
```

When I checked the DB2 diagnostic log, it is showing this entry

```
2015-12-28-13.21.28.810478+330 I187012E411           LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 6446                 TID : 140568303744800 PROC : db2havend (db2ha)
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: xxxxxxxxx
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, high avail services, db2haAddResource, probe:11286
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Error adding resource db2mnt-mnt_san_db1-rs to group db2_db2inst1_0-rg, resource handle is NOT valid

2015-12-28-13.30.20.027549+330 E189851E371           LEVEL: Error
PID     : 10262                TID : 140256146859808 PROC : db2haicu
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: xxxxxxxx
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, high avail services, SqlhaUIAppContext::getInstance, probe:100
RETCODE : ECF=0x9000052E=-1879046866=ECF_SQLHA_FAILED
          SQLHA API call error
```

The path I created for the database `/mnt/san/db1`.

I have cross checked the pre-requisites for db2haicu clustering multiple times and everything seems fine.

Any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: On which node are you running `db2haicu`? What does `lssam` show?

Comment: I'm running 'db2haicu' on the first node , on which the mount point is mounted initially.  'lssam' also hangs as the setup didn't complete.